# Ошибка в цикле phyton

Tags: python

Пытаюсь изучить питон, не могу понять в чем ошибка, надо решить задачу:
с клавиатуры вводим числа и необходимо посчитать сумму четных, завершить исполнение при пустом вводе.
По итогу сумму считает не верно, хотя логика вроде правильная, подскажите где ошибка может быть

```
summa = 0

while True:
    a = input()
    if a == '':
        break
    else:
        s = int(a)
        for i in range(s):
            if not i % 2:
                summa = summa + i
print(summa)
```

Comment: У вас в программе вводится число `a` и после этого перебираются последовательно натуральные числа от `0` до `a-1` (и проверяются на чётность). Такая ли логика задумывалась? Из описания похоже, что нет.

Comment: вот теперь я понял как range отрабатывает. а логика то конечно была просто в проверке условия что нет остатка при делении на 2. спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
summa = 0

while True:
    a = input()
    if not a:
        break
    s = int(a)
    if not s % 2:
        summa = summa + s
            
print(summa)
```

Comment: вот теперь увидел свою ошибку, не надо было range использовать

Comment: @ДенисЕлсаков да, вы правильно заметили. Ваш способ подойдет если вам надо просуммировать числа с четными индексами.